# How can I make a view that's managed with an Tab Bar fade smoothly in/out rather than flashing hardly in/out?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an Tab Bar controller and a nice tab bar on the bottom of my app. There are three buttons. When I tap one, then the view controller from that tab bar is "invoked" and the new view appears immediately. That's like banging a door very hard, so that everyone in the neighbourhood can hear it. I would like to have a softer transition, if possible. Something like fading out, fading in, or page flip transition. What do I have to look at to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the viewController's `viewWillAppear` method and implementing a view animation that, say, sets the view alpha to 0.0 and moves it up to 1.0 for a fade-in effect. On the way out you could override `viewWillDisappear`.

However, keep in mind that fancy page animations tend to get old and sometimes get in the way after the novelty wears off. Most veteran users just want to get going. If you end up doing something you may want to have a user setting that lets them turn it off.

Comment: In this case it's actually an game, so there that might be appropriate. But you're right, it should be possible to switch that off!